# What is the structure of RCH=NH?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I know that $\ce{RCH=NH}$ is an imine.

What is it's structure?

Comment: Hi! Can you show us your efforts and your attempts, even if this is maybe not a homework q. maybe could be useful to understand where is the problem and the question will be nicer! Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: [Have you tried?](http://en.lmgtfy.com/?q=Imine&l=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Here it is one of the isomers.

Answer (score 3):

The general structure of an imine contains a carbon-nitrogen double bound.

[image]

You can add hydrogen atoms or organic groups instead of $R^1$, $R^2$ or $R^3$.

The structure of your formula is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The structure of an imine is analogous to that of an olefin.  There is a central $\ce{C-N}$ sigma bond along with a pi bond just as in an olefin. In the figure below, the olefin has four substituents attached to the two carbons forming the carbon-carbon double bond.[image]

All 6 of these atoms or groups lie in the same plane, the plane of the screen.  Similarly in an imine, all of the groups attached to the central $\ce{C=N}$ double bond also lie in the plane of the screen, along with the carbon and nitrogen atoms themselves.  Note that while the olefin had four substituents ($\ce{R_1 - R_4}$), the imine has only 3 substituents.  The fourth substituent position in the imine is occupied by a lone pair of electrons on the imine nitrogen.  This gives rise to an important difference between olefins and imines.  Appropriately substituted olefins can exist as *cis-trans* pairs.  It typically takes energies in excess of 60 kcal/mol to break the pi bond portion of a carbon-carbon double bond and cause *cis-trans* isomerization.  The barrier for interconversion (called *syn-anti* isomerization in imines) in an imine is much lower, on the order of 20 kcal/mol, so rotation about the imine double bond occurs much more readily than in the olefin case.